# How to include the overbrace in the below matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, overbrace

Suppose, the below matrix is a n*n matrix with n-k entries 1 and rest k entries 0. I want to add two overbraces over the first row, one is upto all 1 mentioning n-k and the other one is all 0 mentioning k.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 &  \dots & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0    \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
   0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & \dots & \dots & \dots & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & \dots & 1  \\
   1 & 1 & 0 & \dots  & 0  & 0 & 1 & \dots  & 1  \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots &\ddots & \vdots  \\
   1 & 1 &  \dots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- please always provide, if possible, a small but complete document (with your matrix), which we can compile as it is
- your problem is possible simple solve by use of the `nicematrix` package
- using it, you need to compile two or three times that you will get final format

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nicematrix}

    
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1      & 1      &        & \dots  & 1      & 1      & 0      & \dots  & 0       \\
0      & 1      & 1      & \dots  & 1      & 1      & 0      & \dots  & 0       \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0      & 0      &  \dots &      0 & 1      &  \dots & \dots  &  \dots & 1       \\
1      & 0      &  \dots & 0      & 0      & 1      & \dots  &  \dots & 1       \\
1      & 1      & 0      & \dots  & 0      & 0      & 1      &  \dots & 1       \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
1      & 1      &  \dots & 1      & 0      & 0      &  \dots & 0      & 1       \\
\CodeAfter
\OverBrace[shorten,yshift=5pt]{1-1}{2-6}{1}
\OverBrace[shorten,yshift=5pt]{1-7}{2-9}{0}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for edit!

Comment: You're very welcome. I too have sometimes typos, and forget to check what I typedbefore posting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bernard!!